# how to show user location on Google maps using "onclick" function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, onclick, geolocation

I'm trying to build a website that shows a map and on top of it I want to display a button that takes you to your current location.
I'm using Google maps service to pull out the map, I also manage to get the user location by itself so all the JavaScript seems to be working fine but when add the function getlocation to the code and try to call it from the HTML it doesn't work. I believe that is probably not finding the function and I can't figure out why?
I will leave the code below:

```
<script>
 var map;

function initialize() {

var miami = new google.maps.LatLng(41.85, -87.65);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: miami,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'),
                                mapOptions);

  var myloc = document.getElementById("try");

  function getlocation () {
    //code

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
  }


function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);


}
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

I'm using inline style for everything. I'm somehow new into this of JavaScript so if could please tell me where is my error or what else do I need to make a button from the HTML call a function on JavaScript.
In addition here is the HTML button and map div

```
    <style>
  html, body, #mymap{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="try"><button onclick="getlocation()">Click here</button></div>
    <div id="mymap"></div>
  </body>
```

If you don't understand what my question is please also comment!
This is my first question here!

Comment: You can look into some `IP Geo API`'s. Some will give you the `longitude`/`latitude` of that IP, then you can insert the `longitude`/`latitude` into a variable or put it into the function call as an argument. Keep in mind `**Geo data is only rough**` and some IP's will not return a specific location / state/city/town so correct validation on the data would be recommended.

Comment: I saw many ways to get the user Location using js on google maps what I don't know is how to call that function using a button outside the map or even inside the map.
I'm just trying to find a way to create a button that takes me to the user current position.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});

});
```

Comment: so you are saying I should add that in my js?
though I don't want a marker I just want that the button on my HTML takes me to the user current position

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. 
Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers.

Comment: on clicking it takes you to the user location and also you will get the latitudes

Comment: Just a slight change to the above code: call `google.maps.event.addDomListener(...)` instead. Then you just have to replace the line `marker = new google...` with `getLocation()`. Assuming your `getLocation()` works correctly, this will trigger your function when the user clicks anywhere on the map.

Comment: One more thing, take `getlocation()` out of the `initialize` function.